# Pandas read_csv dtype inference on file with many int columns, except index and columns are string

Tags: python, pandas, csv, types, type-inference

I need to load a big .csv file (with something like 10 million records) for my recommender I am building. My input file looks like this (with k near ~400 columns):

```
      P1    P2    ... Pk

a      1     1    ...  0
b      0     0    ...  0
c      0     0    ...  1
```

I try to read my file with this call:

```
pd.read_csv(url,header=0, sep="\t",index_col=0,encoding="utf-8")
```

When I read the file, Pandas **incorrectly guesses that all the numbers in my data are floats**. I want to force the data to be 'int' type in order to save memory in the loading process. I tried to use the option: `dtype=int`, but this issued an error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'
```

I guess that this is due to the fact that my index and columns are strings.

I know that I could try to use a dictionary to specify the data types for the columns manually, but since I am building a recommender **don't know the columns and the indexes of my files in advance**, and I want to avoid to re-create the dictionary each time a new file is lodaded.

How can I specify to the `read_csv` method to **set the integer type only on the data of my table, and not for the index and the column names?**

Answer (score 1):

**Approach 1:** In case you have only a few columns with non-default data types, you could use a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html):

```py
from collections import defaultdict
dtypes = defaultdict(lambda: int)
dtypes["index_column"] = str 
dtypes["other_special_column"] = object
# ...
df = pd.read_csv(path, dtype=dtypes, ...)
```

How this works: `dtypes["something"]` returns by default type `int`, except for the columns that have been specified beforehand.

**Approach 2:** In case the `dtype` can be inferred safely by reading only a part of the .csv, you could do the following:

```py
n = 1000
df = pd.read_csv(path, nrows=n, ...)
df = pd.read_csv(path, dtype=df.dtypes, ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Method 1) Use `apply()` on dataframe with a function which does error-safe coercion to int if it can:

```
df = pd.read_csv(url,header=0, sep="\t",index_col=0,encoding="utf-8")

def check_to_int(x):
    try:
        return int(x)
    except:
        return x

for i in df.columns:
    df[i] = df[i].apply(check_to_int)
```

If have any further problem with datatype (which is like), please post.

#### Method 2) Dynamically read the header row(s) of your dataframe to detect which columns are int/float (given you don't know your csv column names), then create a dict for `dtypes` with those names.

For example, if I had the dataframe:

```
    |user_id    |screen_name    |isocode    |location_name   |location_prob
0   |1058941868 |scottspur      |           |                |
1   |1058941921 |Roxy22Bennett  |           |                |
2   |105894357  |MerrynPreece   |GB         |United Kingdom  |0.998043
```

So I must check the '2' row:

```
a = pd.read_csv('Result_Phong1.csv',header=0, encoding="utf-8", nrows = 3)
a.fillna('', inplace=True)

temp = []
for i in a.loc[2,:].index:
    if type(a.loc[2,:][i]) == float:
        temp.append(i)
```

and the result would be:

```
Out[46]: [u'location_prob']
```

Then you can create a dict of them to pass in read_csv function.

Comment: I don't want to use a function over the loaded datafrane, due to memory usage. I just want to know if there exist a way to properly configure the read_csv method to set the correct datatype, in order to gain some Memory Space.

In your solution I would load the whole dataframe as float64 and then after create a copy of it in memory, and that is not helpful for me at the moment. Thanks anyway

Comment: It is totally unnecessary defining a custom function, just use [`astype(..., errors='ignore')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html)